# WPF: create a binding to a nested property in code behind

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, viewmodel

I have the following multibinding in my xaml file:

```
<MyControl:CommandParameter>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{commonConverters:MultiBindingConverter}">
         <Binding Path="CurrentItem.Id" />
         <Binding Path="SelectedItem.Count" />
     </MultiBinding>
</Mycontrol:CommandParameter>
```

How can i define this multibinding in my viewmodel?
Or, when this is not possible, how can I define in my viewmodel that the CanExecute of the command is triggered every time the Id or Count changes?

Another difficulty is that CurrentItem and SelectedItem can be null after initialization and will be initialized while using the application.

Thanks!

Comment: The `CanExecute` is a separate binding, not part of the multibinding above. The ICommand that it is bound to should simply evaluate the two properties in question. And you should not define a binding in your VM, that is bad design (the VM wshould be agnostic of the view it is bound to).

Answer (score 0):

To tell WPF your command may have become executable or not executable you can use the [`ICommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged?view=net-5.0) event. It'll make WPF call the `CanExecute` method of your command.

Since you didn't provide your ViewModel's and SelectedItem/CurrentItem's code the following example may not represent your use case but it'll give you the general idea.

Consider having the following custom command class :

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    public EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        // determine if command can be executed
    }
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        this.CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In your ViewModel you could then have something that looks like this

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private int _id;
    public MyCommand SomeCommand { get; set; }
    public int Id 
    { 
        get => _id;
        set
        {
            // do other stuff (ie: property changed notification)
            SomeCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
}
```